# T-SQL 2012- How can I pair down query and check the returned values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which captures various events and returns data as below

```
+----+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
| ID | EventType | SystemUserID | OrganisationID  |
+----+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
| 23 |         8 |           11 |               1 |
| 44 |         7 |          456 |             304 |
| 80 |         1 |           48 |            4042 |
| 89 |         2 |         5673 |             183 |
+----+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

EventType 8 is captured each time a user visits an organisation.

I have another table named OrganisationHasContact as such

```
+----+----------------+--------------+
| ID | OrganisationID | SystemUserID |
+----+----------------+--------------+
| 23 |              1 |           11 |
| 44 |            304 |          456 |
| 80 |           4042 |           48 |
| 89 |            183 |         5673 |
+----+----------------+--------------+
```

I have wrote a query in order to find the total number of visits each organisation has had but excluding SystemUsers who are associated to that organisation

```
SELECT 
OrganisationID AS [OrganisationID], 
ORG.Name AS [Compayny Name],
Count(OrganisationID) AS [Visits]
FROM [Audit].[EventData]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employed.Organisation AS ORG ON [EventData].OrganisationID = ORG.ID
Where Not Exists(
        Select * From [Audit].[EventData] AS A2
        Inner join Employed.OrganisationHasContact AS OHC On [EventData].OrganisationIDID = OHC.OrganisationID
        Where OHC.SystemUserID = [EventData].SystemUserID 
      )
AND
EventTypeID = 8
Group BY [EventData].OrganisationID,
         ORG.Name
Order By Visits Desc
```

To test the above query was returning correct values (449 visits) I did the following

First I ran this query to get all SystemUserId's associated to Org 1741

```
Select * from Employed.OrganisationHasContact 
Where OrganisationID = 1741
```

Then with the returned SystemUserID's I ran this query

```
SELECT Distinct
OrganisationID AS [OrganisationID], 
ORG.Name AS [Compayny Name],
Count(OrganisationID) AS [Visits]
FROM [Audit].[EventData]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employed.Organisation AS ORG ON [EventData].OrganisationID = ORG.ID
Where
EventTypeID = 8
AND SystemUserID NOT IN (35, 4602, 48, 4603, 7704)
Group BY OrganisationID,
         ORG.Name
Order By Visits Desc
```

This Returned 446 visits for Org 1741, my original query returns 449 visits.

What could be causing the difference?

Can I improve my original query somehow?

Is there a better way to test this?

Thanks

Comment: Usually when I need to test things where I suspect, I return incorrect - I use the EXCEPT / INTERSECT between my original query and the modified one, so I can see which results are there now which weren't there before - or vice versa. This leads me to what I've done incorrectly or verify it's correct.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used these operators before but will take a look into them.